# Error: Archivo '../*.aspx' no existe Application_Error Global.Asax

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

El error se da cuando cambié la versión del Framework de 4.0 a 4.5.1.

En el framework anterior no daba ese problema.

Cuando entra por primera vez a cualquier página (ejemplo: '**Sitio/Carpeta/Pagina.aspx**') carga bien, pero cuando realiza el postback se cae por el siguiente error:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): **The file '/Sitio/Pagina.aspx' does not exist.**
>      at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
>      at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

En el **Web.config** tiene lo siguiente:

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
```

Comment: Saludos Adrian, bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo revisar https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que te familiarices con el sitio. Por curiosidad, ¿Has modificado el aspx.designer.cs?

Comment: No se ha editado, Saludos